# SSRS Report in 1:N relation

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml

Please guide me about this. I am working on CRM online.

I need report(custom SSRS) which will be invoked from Campaign and it will print all the Leads belongs to that Campaign.

How should i achieve this.

I created a master report based on Campaign, and a child report which is added inside that master report using BIDS.

I am passing campaignId to the child and child report does it work simply.

**Is it possible using single report instead of two report...??**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a single report, isn't mandatory to use the Parent-Child relationship that is available with Dynamics CRM.

Inside your report you can create how many dataset you want, just define a dataset with a  query (built with `FetchXml` because you are using CRM Online) that will fetch for the related leads of the selected campaign.

You can use Advanced Find to get the `FetchXml` to start.

Example:
you have the `FetchXml` from the Advanced Find, this will retrieve all the leads with the attribute `new_campaignid` as the selected GUID value.

```xml
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="lead">
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <attribute name="companyname" />
    <attribute name="telephone1" />
    <attribute name="leadid" />
    <order attribute="fullname" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="new_campaignid" operator="eq" uiname="Test Campaign" uitype="campaign" value="{F7038DE4-B5A5-E211-8417-000C29E20CBC}" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

after create the dataset, I attached a screenshot of BIDS

[image]

Comment: dataset? I have no idea about dataset in Fetch XML reporting service.
Can you please provide some examples or something so that i can start.

Really i want to  implement this if this is possible using single report.

Please help, Thanks

Comment: So, here i need to create 2 Dataset. One for Campaign and another for Lead?

Then how Dataset for Lead will receive campaignId from first Dataset?

Comment: if the first dataset get the campaignid from a parameter, you can create the second dataset to get the same parameter too.